# Sum a list of numbers until a number X is found

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sum

In my program I need to put a **while** function which sums this list until a particular number is found:

```
[5,8,1,999,7,5]
```

The output is supposed to be 14, because it sums 5+8+1 and stops when it finds 999.

My idea looks like:

```
def mentre(llista):
  while llista != 999:
    solution = sum(llista)
return solution
```

Comment: have you checked the documentation of [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)? and the while loop? You are comparing a `list` (llista) to an `int` (999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of explicitly using a while loop would be as follows:

```
def sum_until_found(lst, num):
    index = 0
    res = 0
    if num in lst:
        while index < lst.index(num):
            res += lst[index]
            index += 1
    else:
        return "The number is not in the list!"
    return res
```

Another possible way is:

```
def sum_until_found(lst, num):
    index = 0
    res = 0
    found = False
    if num in lst:
        while not found:
            res += lst[index]
            index += 1
            if lst[index] == num:
                found = True
    else:
        return "The number is not in the list!"
    return res
```

There's many ways of doing this without using a while loop, one of which is using recursion:

```
def sum_until_found_3(lst, num, res=0):
    if num in lst:
        if lst[0] == num:
            return res
        else:
            return sum_until_found_3(lst[1:], num, res + lst[0])
    else:
        return "The number is not in the list!"
```

Finally, an even simpler solution:

```
def sum_until_found(lst, num):
    if num in lst:
        return sum(lst[:lst.index(num)])
    else:
        return "The number is not in the list!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `iter`-function:

```
>>> l = [5,8,1,999,7,5]
>>> sum(iter(iter(l).next, 999))
14
```

`iter` calls the first argument, until the second argument is found. So all numbers are summed up, till 999 is found.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention using a `while` loop, you could try a generator-based approach using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> l = [5,8,1,999,7,5]
>>> sum(takewhile(lambda a: a != 999, l))
14
```

The generator consumes from the list `l` as long as the predicate (`a != 999`) is true, and these values are summed. The predicate can be anything you like here (like a normal `while` loop), e.g. you could sum the list while the values are less than 500.

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` and slice

```
def mentre(llista):
    solution = sum(lista[:lista.index(999)])
    return solution
```

Demo

```
>>> lista =  [5,8,1,999,7,5] 
>>> sum(lista[:lista.index(999)])
14
```

Comment: nteresting! but I don't think as efficient as iter with a sentinal value or the takewhile. I think those options scan the list once and this options scans the list twice. (I didn't run tests though)

Comment: True. They are better as this is O(n2). :)